# ModernCV long name and title on the same line

Tags: titles, moderncv, width

Is it possible to have a long title and name on the same line in `moderncv`?
Currently, it looks like this: 
[image]

The ideal would be that there is no line break after Juantostos. I tried to uncomment the `\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{12cm}` but it's for the 'classic' style and it also gives a compile error 
`(Undefined control sequence)`.

I'm using Overleaf.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}                            
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{import}

% personal data
\name{John}{Juanostos Buenos}
\title{Curriculum Vitae} 

\address{Something}{Stuff 34 more stuff here}{}
\phone[mobile]{+34 342453533}
\extrainfo{FNAC.: 07/19/1985} 

\email{herecomstheemail@mymail.com}                             

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one option:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox,changepage}
\patchcmd{\makehead}% <cmd>
  {0.8\textwidth}% <search>
  {\linewidth}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

% personal data
\name{John}{Juanostos Buenos}
\title{Curriculum Vitae} 

\address{Something}{Stuff 34 more stuff here}{}
\phone[mobile]{+34 342453533}
\extrainfo{FNAC.: 07/19/1985}

\email{herecomstheemail@mymail.com}

\begin{document}

% Increase block width by 1cm on both sides
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
\makecvtitle
X\dotfill X
\end{adjustwidth}

Y\dotfill Y

\end{document}
```

We do two things:

1. Patch `\makehead` to increase the width of the header from `0.8\textwidth` to `\linewidth`. In the very least, this will set it at `\textwidth`. However, since `\textwidth` is rigid (or fixed) we can...
2. ...use `adjustwidth` (from [`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage)) to increase the width temporarily just for the title.

In the above example `X.....X` represents the width used for the title, and `Y.....Y` the width of the subsequent text block.